# Черный экран окна приложения на Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Основной код выглядит так, синтаксически вроде все верно, но при запуске исключительно черный экран.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Код файла .kv

```
<Container>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 3
    spacing: 3

    TextInput:
        text: ''
        multiline: False
        text_size: 40

    Label:
        text: 'Просто текст'
        font_size: 40

    Button:
        text:'Поехали'
```

Comment: Эээ, как бы а кто будет инклюдить .kv?

Answer (score 1):

Измените имя файла на `my.kv` и поместите его в одну папку с py-файлом.
Или измените имя класса:
Например, если ваш kv-файл называется `test.kv`, то назовите класс

```
TestApp(App):
    ...
```

Если kv-файл называется `program`, то класс должен называться

```
class ProgramApp(App):
    ...
```

В конце можно не добавлять App: `class Program(App)` тоже будет работать.